# NLog.Config read from IIS Express folder instead of Content Root

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog, appsettings

I am writing a ASP.NET Core 2.2 service, that is using *Common.Logging* and *NLog*.

I hooked up Common.Logging, with NLog, in the appsettings.json file:

```
  "LogConfiguration": {
    "factoryAdapter": {
      "type": "Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog45",
      "arguments": {
        "configType": "FILE",
        "configFile": "~/nlog.config"
      }
    }
  }
```

And in Startup.cs I added :

```
    var logConfiguration = new LogConfiguration();
    Configuration.GetSection("LogConfiguration").Bind(logConfiguration);
    LogManager.Configure(logConfiguration);
```

When I start my service and the code hits a *logger.Info*, `I get a The type initializer for '...' threw an exception`.

For NLog this usually means no targets were found. I used Procmon.exe to search for a failed access of nlog.config and found an attempt to read: *C:\Program Files\IIS Express\~\nlog.config*.

How can I get IIS Express to look for nlog.config at the Content Root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do as shown in the PullRequest:

```
{
  "LogConfiguration": {
    "factoryAdapter": {
      "type": "Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog45",
      "arguments": {
        "configType": "INLINE",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And let NLog 4.5 load its own LoggingConfiguration.

https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/pull/176

You can also explicit log the NLog.config from the wanted location:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading

Comment: Omg, this indeed works. I was under the impression that when a config is INLINEd, the settings must be in the same file (in this case appsettings.json). And I didn't want to use a web.config in .NET Core.